# video iframe is not displaying the video wordpress https error

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, video, iframe

I am using a customized version of the [gridby theme](http://www.marchettidesign.net/gridby/) I have been adding some new page templates and editing some css over past few days and now I have noticed that the video iframe isnt displaying the actual video. When I inspect the element I can see the area it should be is highlighted. The theme uses a video url field to display a iframe of a video in the single post but I am really stuck now trying to figure out why its not working it was fine few weeks ago I just haven't noticed until now so don't know how to find the error. You can see the post in question [here](https://deborahbux.com/mywork/fashion-2015-stewart-duffy/). thanks in advance

```
    /*!
 * jQuery Migrate - v1.4.1 - 2016-05-19
 * Copyright jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 */
(function( jQuery, window, undefined ) {
// See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13335
// "use strict";


jQuery.migrateVersion = "1.4.1";


var warnedAbout = {};

// List of warnings already given; public read only
jQuery.migrateWarnings = [];

// Set to true to prevent console output; migrateWarnings still maintained
// jQuery.migrateMute = false;

// Show a message on the console so devs know we're active
if ( window.console && window.console.log ) {
    window.console.log( "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed" +
        ( jQuery.migrateMute ? "" : " with logging active" ) +
        ", version " + jQuery.migrateVersion );
}

// Set to false to disable traces that appear with warnings
if ( jQuery.migrateTrace === undefined ) {
    jQuery.migrateTrace = true;
}

// Forget any warnings we've already given; public
jQuery.migrateReset = function() {
    warnedAbout = {};
    jQuery.migrateWarnings.length = 0;
};

function migrateWarn( msg) {
    var console = window.console;
    if ( !warnedAbout[ msg ] ) {
        warnedAbout[ msg ] = true;
        jQuery.migrateWarnings.push( msg );
        if ( console && console.warn && !jQuery.migrateMute ) {
            console.warn( "JQMIGRATE: " + msg );
            if ( jQuery.migrateTrace && console.trace ) {
                console.trace();
            }
        }
    }
}

function migrateWarnProp( obj, prop, value, msg ) {
    if ( Object.defineProperty ) {
        // On ES5 browsers (non-oldIE), warn if the code tries to get prop;
        // allow property to be overwritten in case some other plugin wants it
        try {
            Object.defineProperty( obj, prop, {
                configurable: true,
                enumerable: true,
                get: function() {
                    migrateWarn( msg );
                    return value;
                },
                set: function( newValue ) {
                    migrateWarn( msg );
                    value = newValue;
                }
            });
            return;
        } catch( err ) {
            // IE8 is a dope about Object.defineProperty, can't warn there
        }
    }

    // Non-ES5 (or broken) browser; just set the property
    jQuery._definePropertyBroken = true;
    obj[ prop ] = value;
}

if ( document.compatMode === "BackCompat" ) {
    // jQuery has never supported or tested Quirks Mode
    migrateWarn( "jQuery is not compatible with Quirks Mode" );
}


var attrFn = jQuery( "<input/>", { size: 1 } ).attr("size") && jQuery.attrFn,
    oldAttr = jQuery.attr,
    valueAttrGet = jQuery.attrHooks.value && jQuery.attrHooks.value.get ||
        function() { return null; },
    valueAttrSet = jQuery.attrHooks.value && jQuery.attrHooks.value.set ||
        function() { return undefined; },
    rnoType = /^(?:input|button)$/i,
    rnoAttrNodeType = /^[238]$/,
    rboolean = /^(?:autofocus|autoplay|async|checked|controls|defer|disabled|hidden|loop|multiple|open|readonly|required|scoped|selected)$/i,
    ruseDefault = /^(?:checked|selected)$/i;

// jQuery.attrFn
migrateWarnProp( jQuery, "attrFn", attrFn || {}, "jQuery.attrFn is deprecated" );

jQuery.attr = function( elem, name, value, pass ) {
    var lowerName = name.toLowerCase(),
        nType = elem && elem.nodeType;

    if ( pass ) {
        // Since pass is used internally, we only warn for new jQuery
        // versions where there isn't a pass arg in the formal params
        if ( oldAttr.length < 4 ) {
            migrateWarn("jQuery.fn.attr( props, pass ) is deprecated");
        }
        if ( elem && !rnoAttrNodeType.test( nType ) &&
            (attrFn ? name in attrFn : jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn[name])) ) {
            return jQuery( elem )[ name ]( value );
        }
    }

    // Warn if user tries to set `type`, since it breaks on IE 6/7/8; by checking
    // for disconnected elements we don't warn on $( "<button>", { type: "button" } ).
    if ( name === "type" && value !== undefined && rnoType.test( elem.nodeName ) && elem.parentNode ) {
        migrateWarn("Can't change the 'type' of an input or button in IE 6/7/8");
    }

    // Restore boolHook for boolean property/attribute synchronization
    if ( !jQuery.attrHooks[ lowerName ] && rboolean.test( lowerName ) ) {
        jQuery.attrHooks[ lowerName ] = {
            get: function( elem, name ) {
                // Align boolean attributes with corresponding properties
                // Fall back to attribute presence where some booleans are not supported
                var attrNode,
                    property = jQuery.prop( elem, name );
                return property === true || typeof property !== "boolean" &&
                    ( attrNode = elem.getAttributeNode(name) ) && attrNode.nodeValue !== false ?

                    name.toLowerCase() :
                    undefined;
            },
            set: function( elem, value, name ) {
                var propName;
                if ( value === false ) {
                    // Remove boolean attributes when set to false
                    jQuery.removeAttr( elem, name );
                } else {
                    // value is true since we know at this point it's type boolean and not false
                    // Set boolean attributes to the same name and set the DOM property
                    propName = jQuery.propFix[ name ] || name;
                    if ( propName in elem ) {
                        // Only set the IDL specifically if it already exists on the element
                        elem[ propName ] = true;
                    }

                    elem.setAttribute( name, name.toLowerCase() );
                }
                return name;
            }
        };

        // Warn only for attributes that can remain distinct from their properties post-1.9
        if ( ruseDefault.test( lowerName ) ) {
            migrateWarn( "jQuery.fn.attr('" + lowerName + "') might use property instead of attribute" );
        }
    }

    return oldAttr.call( jQuery, elem, name, value );
};

// attrHooks: value
jQuery.attrHooks.value = {
    get: function( elem, name ) {
        var nodeName = ( elem.nodeName || "" ).toLowerCase();
        if ( nodeName === "button" ) {
            return valueAttrGet.apply( this, arguments );
        }
        if ( nodeName !== "input" && nodeName !== "option" ) {
            migrateWarn("jQuery.fn.attr('value') no longer gets properties");
        }
        return name in elem ?
            elem.value :
            null;
    },
    set: function( elem, value ) {
        var nodeName = ( elem.nodeName || "" ).toLowerCase();
        if ( nodeName === "button" ) {
            return valueAttrSet.apply( this, arguments );
        }
        if ( nodeName !== "input" && nodeName !== "option" ) {
            migrateWarn("jQuery.fn.attr('value', val) no longer sets properties");
        }
        // Does not return so that setAttribute is also used
        elem.value = value;
    }
};


var matched, browser,
    oldInit = jQuery.fn.init,
    oldFind = jQuery.find,
    oldParseJSON = jQuery.parseJSON,
    rspaceAngle = /^\s*</,
    rattrHashTest = /\[(\s*[-\w]+\s*)([~|^$*]?=)\s*([-\w#]*?#[-\w#]*)\s*\]/,
    rattrHashGlob = /\[(\s*[-\w]+\s*)([~|^$*]?=)\s*([-\w#]*?#[-\w#]*)\s*\]/g,
    // Note: XSS check is done below after string is trimmed
    rquickExpr = /^([^<]*)(<[\w\W]+>)([^>]*)$/;

// $(html) "looks like html" rule change
jQuery.fn.init = function( selector, context, rootjQuery ) {
    var match, ret;

    if ( selector && typeof selector === "string" ) {
        if ( !jQuery.isPlainObject( context ) &&
                (match = rquickExpr.exec( jQuery.trim( selector ) )) && match[ 0 ] ) {

            // This is an HTML string according to the "old" rules; is it still?
            if ( !rspaceAngle.test( selector ) ) {
                migrateWarn("$(html) HTML strings must start with '<' character");
            }
            if ( match[ 3 ] ) {
                migrateWarn("$(html) HTML text after last tag is ignored");
            }

            // Consistently reject any HTML-like string starting with a hash (gh-9521)
            // Note that this may break jQuery 1.6.x code that otherwise would work.
            if ( match[ 0 ].charAt( 0 ) === "#" ) {
                migrateWarn("HTML string cannot start with a '#' character");
                jQuery.error("JQMIGRATE: Invalid selector string (XSS)");
            }

            // Now process using loose rules; let pre-1.8 play too
            // Is this a jQuery context? parseHTML expects a DOM element (#178)
            if ( context && context.context && context.context.nodeType ) {
                context = context.context;
            }

            if ( jQuery.parseHTML ) {
                return oldInit.call( this,
                        jQuery.parseHTML( match[ 2 ], context && context.ownerDocument ||
                            context || document, true ), context, rootjQuery );
            }
        }
    }

    ret = oldInit.apply( this, arguments );

    // Fill in selector and context properties so .live() works
    if ( selector && selector.selector !== undefined ) {
        // A jQuery object, copy its properties
        ret.selector = selector.selector;
        ret.context = selector.context;

    } else {
        ret.selector = typeof selector === "string" ? selector : "";
        if ( selector ) {
            ret.context = selector.nodeType? selector : context || document;
        }
    }

    return ret;
};
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;

jQuery.find = function( selector ) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );

    // Support: PhantomJS 1.x
    // String#match fails to match when used with a //g RegExp, only on some strings
    if ( typeof selector === "string" && rattrHashTest.test( selector ) ) {

        // The nonstandard and undocumented unquoted-hash was removed in jQuery 1.12.0
        // First see if qS thinks it's a valid selector, if so avoid a false positive
        try {
            document.querySelector( selector );
        } catch ( err1 ) {

            // Didn't *look* valid to qSA, warn and try quoting what we think is the value
            selector = selector.replace( rattrHashGlob, function( _, attr, op, value ) {
                return "[" + attr + op + "\"" + value + "\"]";
            } );

            // If the regexp *may* have created an invalid selector, don't update it
            // Note that there may be false alarms if selector uses jQuery extensions
            try {
                document.querySelector( selector );
                migrateWarn( "Attribute selector with '#' must be quoted: " + args[ 0 ] );
                args[ 0 ] = selector;
            } catch ( err2 ) {
                migrateWarn( "Attribute selector with '#' was not fixed: " + args[ 0 ] );
            }
        }
    }

    return oldFind.apply( this, args );
};

// Copy properties attached to original jQuery.find method (e.g. .attr, .isXML)
var findProp;
for ( findProp in oldFind ) {
    if ( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( oldFind, findProp ) ) {
        jQuery.find[ findProp ] = oldFind[ findProp ];
    }
}

// Let $.parseJSON(falsy_value) return null
jQuery.parseJSON = function( json ) {
    if ( !json ) {
        migrateWarn("jQuery.parseJSON requires a valid JSON string");
        return null;
    }
    return oldParseJSON.apply( this, arguments );
};

jQuery.uaMatch = function( ua ) {
    ua = ua.toLowerCase();

    var match = /(chrome)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        /(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        /(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        /(msie) ([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
        ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec( ua ) ||
        [];

    return {
        browser: match[ 1 ] || "",
        version: match[ 2 ] || "0"
    };
};

// Don't clobber any existing jQuery.browser in case it's different
if ( !jQuery.browser ) {
    matched = jQuery.uaMatch( navigator.userAgent );
    browser = {};

    if ( matched.browser ) {
        browser[ matched.browser ] = true;
        browser.version = matched.version;
    }

    // Chrome is Webkit, but Webkit is also Safari.
    if ( browser.chrome ) {
        browser.webkit = true;
    } else if ( browser.webkit ) {
        browser.safari = true;
    }

    jQuery.browser = browser;
}

// Warn if the code tries to get jQuery.browser
migrateWarnProp( jQuery, "browser", jQuery.browser, "jQuery.browser is deprecated" );

// jQuery.boxModel deprecated in 1.3, jQuery.support.boxModel deprecated in 1.7
jQuery.boxModel = jQuery.support.boxModel = (document.compatMode === "CSS1Compat");
migrateWarnProp( jQuery, "boxModel", jQuery.boxModel, "jQuery.boxModel is deprecated" );
migrateWarnProp( jQuery.support, "boxModel", jQuery.support.boxModel, "jQuery.support.boxModel is deprecated" );

jQuery.sub = function() {
    function jQuerySub( selector, context ) {
        return new jQuerySub.fn.init( selector, context );
    }
    jQuery.extend( true, jQuerySub, this );
    jQuerySub.superclass = this;
    jQuerySub.fn = jQuerySub.prototype = this();
    jQuerySub.fn.constructor = jQuerySub;
    jQuerySub.sub = this.sub;
    jQuerySub.fn.init = function init( selector, context ) {
        var instance = jQuery.fn.init.call( this, selector, context, rootjQuerySub );
        return instance instanceof jQuerySub ?
            instance :
            jQuerySub( instance );
    };
    jQuerySub.fn.init.prototype = jQuerySub.fn;
    var rootjQuerySub = jQuerySub(document);
    migrateWarn( "jQuery.sub() is deprecated" );
    return jQuerySub;
};

// The number of elements contained in the matched element set
jQuery.fn.size = function() {
    migrateWarn( "jQuery.fn.size() is deprecated; use the .length property" );
    return this.length;
};


var internalSwapCall = false;

// If this version of jQuery has .swap(), don't false-alarm on internal uses
if ( jQuery.swap ) {
    jQuery.each( [ "height", "width", "reliableMarginRight" ], function( _, name ) {
        var oldHook = jQuery.cssHooks[ name ] && jQuery.cssHooks[ name ].get;

        if ( oldHook ) {
            jQuery.cssHooks[ name ].get = function() {
                var ret;

                internalSwapCall = true;
                ret = oldHook.apply( this, arguments );
                internalSwapCall = false;
                return ret;
            };
        }
    });
}

jQuery.swap = function( elem, options, callback, args ) {
    var ret, name,
        old = {};

    if ( !internalSwapCall ) {
        migrateWarn( "jQuery.swap() is undocumented and deprecated" );
    }

    // Remember the old values, and insert the new ones
    for ( name in options ) {
        old[ name ] = elem.style[ name ];
        elem.style[ name ] = options[ name ];
    }

    ret = callback.apply( elem, args || [] );

    // Revert the old values
    for ( name in options ) {
        elem.style[ name ] = old[ name ];
    }

    return ret;
};


// Ensure that $.ajax gets the new parseJSON defined in core.js
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    converters: {
        "text json": jQuery.parseJSON
    }
});


var oldFnData = jQuery.fn.data;

jQuery.fn.data = function( name ) {
    var ret, evt,
        elem = this[0];

    // Handles 1.7 which has this behavior and 1.8 which doesn't
    if ( elem && name === "events" && arguments.length === 1 ) {
        ret = jQuery.data( elem, name );
        evt = jQuery._data( elem, name );
        if ( ( ret === undefined || ret === evt ) && evt !== undefined ) {
            migrateWarn("Use of jQuery.fn.data('events') is deprecated");
            return evt;
        }
    }
    return oldFnData.apply( this, arguments );
};


var rscriptType = /\/(java|ecma)script/i;

// Since jQuery.clean is used internally on older versions, we only shim if it's missing
if ( !jQuery.clean ) {
    jQuery.clean = function( elems, context, fragment, scripts ) {
        // Set context per 1.8 logic
        context = context || document;
        context = !context.nodeType && context[0] || context;
        context = context.ownerDocument || context;

        migrateWarn("jQuery.clean() is deprecated");

        var i, elem, handleScript, jsTags,
            ret = [];

        jQuery.merge( ret, jQuery.buildFragment( elems, context ).childNodes );

        // Complex logic lifted directly from jQuery 1.8
        if ( fragment ) {
            // Special handling of each script element
            handleScript = function( elem ) {
                // Check if we consider it executable
                if ( !elem.type || rscriptType.test( elem.type ) ) {
                    // Detach the script and store it in the scripts array (if provided) or the fragment
                    // Return truthy to indicate that it has been handled
                    return scripts ?
                        scripts.push( elem.parentNode ? elem.parentNode.removeChild( elem ) : elem ) :
                        fragment.appendChild( elem );
                }
            };

            for ( i = 0; (elem = ret[i]) != null; i++ ) {
                // Check if we're done after handling an executable script
                if ( !( jQuery.nodeName( elem, "script" ) && handleScript( elem ) ) ) {
                    // Append to fragment and handle embedded scripts
                    fragment.appendChild( elem );
                    if ( typeof elem.getElementsByTagName !== "undefined" ) {
                        // handleScript alters the DOM, so use jQuery.merge to ensure snapshot iteration
                        jsTags = jQuery.grep( jQuery.merge( [], elem.getElementsByTagName("script") ), handleScript );

                        // Splice the scripts into ret after their former ancestor and advance our index beyond them
                        ret.splice.apply( ret, [i + 1, 0].concat( jsTags ) );
                        i += jsTags.length;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    };
}

var eventAdd = jQuery.event.add,
    eventRemove = jQuery.event.remove,
    eventTrigger = jQuery.event.trigger,
    oldToggle = jQuery.fn.toggle,
    oldLive = jQuery.fn.live,
    oldDie = jQuery.fn.die,
    oldLoad = jQuery.fn.load,
    ajaxEvents = "ajaxStart|ajaxStop|ajaxSend|ajaxComplete|ajaxError|ajaxSuccess",
    rajaxEvent = new RegExp( "\\b(?:" + ajaxEvents + ")\\b" ),
    rhoverHack = /(?:^|\s)hover(\.\S+|)\b/,
    hoverHack = function( events ) {
        if ( typeof( events ) !== "string" || jQuery.event.special.hover ) {
            return events;
        }
        if ( rhoverHack.test( events ) ) {
            migrateWarn("'hover' pseudo-event is deprecated, use 'mouseenter mouseleave'");
        }
        return events && events.replace( rhoverHack, "mouseenter$1 mouseleave$1" );
    };

// Event props removed in 1.9, put them back if needed; no practical way to warn them
if ( jQuery.event.props && jQuery.event.props[ 0 ] !== "attrChange" ) {
    jQuery.event.props.unshift( "attrChange", "attrName", "relatedNode", "srcElement" );
}

// Undocumented jQuery.event.handle was "deprecated" in jQuery 1.7
if ( jQuery.event.dispatch ) {
    migrateWarnProp( jQuery.event, "handle", jQuery.event.dispatch, "jQuery.event.handle is undocumented and deprecated" );
}

// Support for 'hover' pseudo-event and ajax event warnings
jQuery.event.add = function( elem, types, handler, data, selector ){
    if ( elem !== document && rajaxEvent.test( types ) ) {
        migrateWarn( "AJAX events should be attached to document: " + types );
    }
    eventAdd.call( this, elem, hoverHack( types || "" ), handler, data, selector );
};
jQuery.event.remove = function( elem, types, handler, selector, mappedTypes ){
    eventRemove.call( this, elem, hoverHack( types ) || "", handler, selector, mappedTypes );
};

jQuery.each( [ "load", "unload", "error" ], function( _, name ) {

    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 0 );

        // If this is an ajax load() the first arg should be the string URL;
        // technically this could also be the "Anything" arg of the event .load()
        // which just goes to show why this dumb signature has been deprecated!
        // jQuery custom builds that exclude the Ajax module justifiably die here.
        if ( name === "load" && typeof args[ 0 ] === "string" ) {
            return oldLoad.apply( this, args );
        }

        migrateWarn( "jQuery.fn." + name + "() is deprecated" );

        args.splice( 0, 0, name );
        if ( arguments.length ) {
            return this.bind.apply( this, args );
        }

        // Use .triggerHandler here because:
        // - load and unload events don't need to bubble, only applied to window or image
        // - error event should not bubble to window, although it does pre-1.7
        // See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11820
        this.triggerHandler.apply( this, args );
        return this;
    };

});

jQuery.fn.toggle = function( fn, fn2 ) {

    // Don't mess with animation or css toggles
    if ( !jQuery.isFunction( fn ) || !jQuery.isFunction( fn2 ) ) {
        return oldToggle.apply( this, arguments );
    }
    migrateWarn("jQuery.fn.toggle(handler, handler...) is deprecated");

    // Save reference to arguments for access in closure
    var args = arguments,
        guid = fn.guid || jQuery.guid++,
        i = 0,
        toggler = function( event ) {
            // Figure out which function to execute
            var lastToggle = ( jQuery._data( this, "lastToggle" + fn.guid ) || 0 ) % i;
            jQuery._data( this, "lastToggle" + fn.guid, lastToggle + 1 );

            // Make sure that clicks stop
            event.preventDefault();

            // and execute the function
            return args[ lastToggle ].apply( this, arguments ) || false;
        };

    // link all the functions, so any of them can unbind this click handler
    toggler.guid = guid;
    while ( i < args.length ) {
        args[ i++ ].guid = guid;
    }

    return this.click( toggler );
};

jQuery.fn.live = function( types, data, fn ) {
    migrateWarn("jQuery.fn.live() is deprecated");
    if ( oldLive ) {
        return oldLive.apply( this, arguments );
    }
    jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
    return this;
};

jQuery.fn.die = function( types, fn ) {
    migrateWarn("jQuery.fn.die() is deprecated");
    if ( oldDie ) {
        return oldDie.apply( this, arguments );
    }
    jQuery( this.context ).off( types, this.selector || "**", fn );
    return this;
};

// Turn global events into document-triggered events
jQuery.event.trigger = function( event, data, elem, onlyHandlers  ){
    if ( !elem && !rajaxEvent.test( event ) ) {
        migrateWarn( "Global events are undocumented and deprecated" );
    }
    return eventTrigger.call( this,  event, data, elem || document, onlyHandlers  );
};
jQuery.each( ajaxEvents.split("|"),
    function( _, name ) {
        jQuery.event.special[ name ] = {
            setup: function() {
                var elem = this;

                // The document needs no shimming; must be !== for oldIE
                if ( elem !== document ) {
                    jQuery.event.add( document, name + "." + jQuery.guid, function() {
                        jQuery.event.trigger( name, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ), elem, true );
                    });
                    jQuery._data( this, name, jQuery.guid++ );
                }
                return false;
            },
            teardown: function() {
                if ( this !== document ) {
                    jQuery.event.remove( document, name + "." + jQuery._data( this, name ) );
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
);

jQuery.event.special.ready = {
    setup: function() {
        if ( this === document ) {
            migrateWarn( "'ready' event is deprecated" );
        }
    }
};

var oldSelf = jQuery.fn.andSelf || jQuery.fn.addBack,
    oldFnFind = jQuery.fn.find;

jQuery.fn.andSelf = function() {
    migrateWarn("jQuery.fn.andSelf() replaced by jQuery.fn.addBack()");
    return oldSelf.apply( this, arguments );
};

jQuery.fn.find = function( selector ) {
    var ret = oldFnFind.apply( this, arguments );
    ret.context = this.context;
    ret.selector = this.selector ? this.selector + " " + selector : selector;
    return ret;
};


// jQuery 1.6 did not support Callbacks, do not warn there
if ( jQuery.Callbacks ) {

    var oldDeferred = jQuery.Deferred,
        tuples = [
            // action, add listener, callbacks, .then handlers, final state
            [ "resolve", "done", jQuery.Callbacks("once memory"),
                jQuery.Callbacks("once memory"), "resolved" ],
            [ "reject", "fail", jQuery.Callbacks("once memory"),
                jQuery.Callbacks("once memory"), "rejected" ],
            [ "notify", "progress", jQuery.Callbacks("memory"),
                jQuery.Callbacks("memory") ]
        ];

    jQuery.Deferred = function( func ) {
        var deferred = oldDeferred(),
            promise = deferred.promise();

        deferred.pipe = promise.pipe = function( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
            var fns = arguments;

            migrateWarn( "deferred.pipe() is deprecated" );

            return jQuery.Deferred(function( newDefer ) {
                jQuery.each( tuples, function( i, tuple ) {
                    var fn = jQuery.isFunction( fns[ i ] ) && fns[ i ];
                    // deferred.done(function() { bind to newDefer or newDefer.resolve })
                    // deferred.fail(function() { bind to newDefer or newDefer.reject })
                    // deferred.progress(function() { bind to newDefer or newDefer.notify })
                    deferred[ tuple[1] ](function() {
                        var returned = fn && fn.apply( this, arguments );
                        if ( returned && jQuery.isFunction( returned.promise ) ) {
                            returned.promise()
                                .done( newDefer.resolve )
                                .fail( newDefer.reject )
                                .progress( newDefer.notify );
                        } else {
                            newDefer[ tuple[ 0 ] + "With" ](
                                this === promise ? newDefer.promise() : this,
                                fn ? [ returned ] : arguments
                            );
                        }
                    });
                });
                fns = null;
            }).promise();

        };

        deferred.isResolved = function() {
            migrateWarn( "deferred.isResolved is deprecated" );
            return deferred.state() === "resolved";
        };

        deferred.isRejected = function() {
            migrateWarn( "deferred.isRejected is deprecated" );
            return deferred.state() === "rejected";
        };

        if ( func ) {
            func.call( deferred, deferred );
        }

        return deferred;
    };

}

})( jQuery, window );
```

Comment: add your codes please

Answer (score 0):

Try posting the video on another blank, new page and see if the video works on a different page with a white background.

Also, try making the video a smaller size.

These are some simple tests to see if it works on another page first.  Let me know.

Comment: I just went on to it and there was a warning up beside the bookmark star icon (chrome) that is saying 'this page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources' when I allow the browser to run the script anyway the vimeo iframe shows and the https turns to http and says the page isnt secure. Inspected the page with the console and I got the following error: JQMIGRATE: jQuery.attrFn is deprecated
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:45
jquery-migrate.js:47 console.trace
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js:47. The js is coming from a plugin that must be installed when theme

Comment: There's a php file in the plugin for the video functions I can't fit the code in the post so let me know if the code I posted is useless and I'll edit it and paste that in

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. My site runs off https but the link for the video was set to be http so ssl certifcate was preventing the iframe from loading. I edited the video support php file in the gridby plugin and changed it to http and its working now. I found the solution here: [How to fix a website with blocked mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)